# colorbar for a broken bar chart

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, subplot, colorbar

I am totally new to python. I have made a broken bar chart as a subplot.

[image: load profile in matplotlib]

The loads are color coded based on the magnitude of power. Presently, the apha values are provided manually but I can set ranges, say for 0-50, alpha=0.2. Now I want to add a colorbar on the right side. What is the best approach to go ahead? Any help is most welcomed. Please note that this graph is a subplot. Here's my code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.colors as mcolors
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import matplotlib.cm
from pylab import *
import numpy as np

#code for the previous subplots

ax3.set_title('Load Profile')
ax3.patch.set_facecolor('silver')

barHeight = 3
ticklist = []
def drawLoadDuration(period, starty, opacity):
    ax3.broken_barh((period), (starty, barHeight), alpha=opacity, facecolors='#330033', lw=0)
    ticklist.append(starty+barHeight/2.0)
    return 0

drawLoadDuration([(0, 5), (13, 4), (19, 3), (23, 1)], 3, 0.5)   #Fan
drawLoadDuration([(19, 1)], 9, 0.65)    #Tube Light
drawLoadDuration([(19, 5)], 15, 0.35)   #Bulb
drawLoadDuration([(7, 2), (16, 1)], 21, 0.28)   #Charger
drawLoadDuration([(15, 0.5), (20, 1)], 27, 0.7) #Television
drawLoadDuration([(9, 1), (17, 1)], 33, 1)  #Pump
drawLoadDuration([(2,4)], 39, 0.8)    #Scooter

ax3.set_ylim(0, 45)
ax3.set_xlim(0, 24)
ax3.set_xlabel('Time (Hours)')
ax3.set_yticks(ticklist)
ax3.set_xticks([0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, 3, 3.5, 4, 4.5, 5, 5.5, 6, 6.5, 7, 7.5, 8, 8.5, 9, 9.5, 10, 10.5, 11, 11.5, 12, 12.5, 13, 13.5, 14, 14.5, 15, 15.5, 16, 16.5, 17, 17.5, 18, 18.5, 19, 19.5, 20, 20.5, 21, 21.5, 22, 22.5, 23, 23.5, 24])
ax3.set_xticklabels(['', '1am', '', '2am', '', '3am', '', '4am', '', '5am', '', '6am', '', '7am', '', '8am', '', '9am', '', '10am', '', '11am', '', '12pm', '', '1pm', '', '2pm', '', '3pm', '', '4pm', '', '5pm', '', '6pm', '', '7pm', '', '8pm', '', '9pm', '', '10pm', '', '11pm', '', '12am'], fontsize='9')
ax3.tick_params('x', colors='MidnightBlue')
ax3.set_yticklabels(['Fan', 'Tube light', 'Bulb', 'Cellphone Charger', 'Television', 'Pump', 'Scooter'])
ax3.grid(True)

f.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.24, right=0.93, left=0.11)
plt.setp([a.get_xticklabels() for a in f.axes[:-1]], visible=False)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might use the concept of a colormap. A colormap maps values between 0. and 1. to a color. So instead of using a fixed color and adjusting the opacity as a function of the input value, you might obtain a color for the bar according to the colormap.

The advantage is that you can later use exactly this colormap to create a colorbar.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.cm
import numpy as np

fig, ax3 = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,4))

ax3.set_title('Load Profile')
ax3.patch.set_facecolor('silver')

# use a colormap
cmap = plt.cm.Blues

barHeight = 3
ticklist = []
def drawLoadDuration(period, starty, opacity):
    # facecolor according to colormap
    ax3.broken_barh((period), (starty, barHeight), facecolors=cmap(opacity), 
                                                    lw=0, zorder=2)
    ticklist.append(starty+barHeight/2.0)

drawLoadDuration([(0, 5), (13, 4), (19, 3), (23, 1)], 3, 0.5)   #Fan
drawLoadDuration([(19, 1)], 9, 0.65)    #Tube Light
drawLoadDuration([(19, 5)], 15, 0.35)   #Bulb
drawLoadDuration([(7, 2), (16, 1)], 21, 0.28)   #Charger
drawLoadDuration([(15, 0.5), (20, 1)], 27, 0.7) #Television
drawLoadDuration([(9, 1), (17, 1)], 33, 1)  #Pump
drawLoadDuration([(2,4)], 39, 0.8)    #Scooter

ax3.set_ylim(0, 45)
ax3.set_xlim(0, 24)
ax3.set_xlabel('Time (Hours)')
ax3.set_yticks(ticklist)
xticklist = np.linspace(0.5, 24, 48)
ax3.set_xticks(xticklist)
ax3.set_xticklabels(["{}{}m".format(int(h%12+12*(h%12==0)),
                     {0:"p",1:"a"}[(h%24)<12]) if ((h*10)%10)==0 \
                    else "" for h in xticklist], fontsize='9', rotation=90)
ax3.tick_params('x', colors=cmap(1.))
ax3.set_yticklabels(['Fan', 'Tube light', 'Bulb', 'Cellphone Charger', 
                                         'Television', 'Pump', 'Scooter'])
ax3.grid(True)

# create a scalarmappable from the colormap
sm = matplotlib.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cmap)
sm.set_array([])
# and use this scalarmappable to create a colorbar
fig.colorbar(sm, ax=ax3,label="load")


fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.24, right=0.93, left=0.2, bottom=0.2)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! How may I color code the values?
For ex, (for 100-500 W, opacity=0.5)?
Also, I need to adjust the size according to the other subplots. Thanks Again!

Comment: I thought that you wanted to use a colorbar to have a continuous mapping, i.e. 50 W is lighter in color than 100 W and 100 W is lighter in color than 150 W and so forth. Since I now don't know what you really want, you would best descibe it in detail in the question. What should the colorbar look like? Which colors should be where?

Comment: Concerning the size, this is probably a different question; you may start [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/axes_grid/demo_axes_divider.html) and there are already a couple of questions about colorbars and subplots around. If they don't help, ask a new one with your specific subplot arangement.